# clone() not visible

Tags: java, generics, clone

I have a class:

```
public class CounterBag<T extends Additive<T> & Cloneable & Serializable> {
    private T cntData;

    // c'tor, accessors equals and hashcode... 
    public T getCounterData() {
       return cntData;
    }
}
```

other class `Service` has a member of type `Set<CounterBag>`.
Now inside the `Service` I want to lookup for specific `CounterBag` and return a clone of its `cntData` member.

When inside the lookup method of the `Service` class I detect the instance of the `CounterBag` in the set and try to the following:

```
return counterBag.getCounterData().clone();
```

the `clone()` seems not to be visible.

I wonder what needs to be done to make the `clone()` visible?

Comment: [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) doesn't say anything about `clone()` method. If you want to call `clone()` on `T`, one of it's interfaces must contain `clone()` method. `Cloneable` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cloneable` does not (re)declare the `clone` method, it's simply inherited from `Object`. That means instances of `T` aren't known to have a visible implementation of `clone`. Define your own subinterface of `Cloneable` which declares `clone` and use it as a bound on `T`. If you can't because you don't have control over the various concrete `T`s then you will have to resort to reflection. :(

Comment: Why does it have to be a subinterface of `Cloneable`? `Cloneable` only affects the behavior of `Object.clone()`. A class might use a clone method that does not use `Object.clone()`; then there is no need for it to implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: @newacct I suggested it be a subinterface of `Cloneable` so as to preserve that bound on `T`. Yet, you make a good argument; semantically it's not quite right. In my mind `Cloneable` means/meant just what it says, but really what it means is `Object.clone()` won't throw. I guess what it comes down to is how many people will make that distinction.

Answer (score 1):

`clone` method is by default define in `Object` class and it is a `protected` member of the class.

From `Object` class :

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

So, You will have to define `clone` method in your `CounterBag` class. Then only it will be available.

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
```

You will have to define it as a public method, to make it available out of the package.

Comment: I think `T` should have a visible implementation of `clone()` method and not `CounterBag` class.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the class that is passed as the `T` type parameter implements `Cloneable` with the appropriate visibility, for example:

```
@Override
public Object clone() {
    try {
        return super.clone();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // either handle the exception or throw it
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just remember that the method [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)  is marked as `protected` in the `Object` class, and you need to make it visible in your own classes.

Comment: I don't know what will be the concrete implementation of `T`. I just declare it as `T extends Additive<T> & Cloneable & Serializable`, so the concrete implementation will be aware of the fact that clone abilities are expected. However, I guess that is not enough.

Comment: @aviad but anyway the concrete implementation of T must provide a correct implementation of clone(), there's no way out of it.

Comment: Sure, but this does not help me to call the `clone()` on instance of T type - it is still not visible, since the default `clone()` of the `Object` has visibility `protected`.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it in the class `CounterBag`, it's the entire responsibility of the `T` classes to provide a visible implementation of clone()

Comment: Anything I can do in the `CounterBag`declaration? Except for creating `MyCloneable` with public `clone()` and then using `MyCloneable` in the CounterBag declaration? (`CounterBag<T extends Additive<T> & MyCloneable & Serializable>`)

Comment: @aviad but still, you'd need to implement a visible version of clone() in the classes that implement MyCloneable... take it as a rule in your T's: if they're to be cloneable, then they must override clone with a public method.